# How Can I Use Use curl Check for Oulook(owa) Login Success or Failure?

Tags: bash, curl, outlook

I know that the basic command is:

```
curl  --data "destination=$1&flags=4&forcedownlevel=0&trusted=4&username=$i&password=$pass&isUtf8=1" https://$3/
```

But how can I check to see if the login results in success or failure?

EDIT: To be specific, I want to know if the login is successful or if it failed, *not* if the curl command has succeeded or failed.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the return value :

```
    curl  --data "destination=$1&flags=4&forcedownlevel=0&trusted=4&username=$i&password=$pass&isUtf8=1" https://$3/
    ret=$?

    echo "return value is $ret"
    if [ $ret != 0 ];then
       echo "call failed"
    fi
```

Comment: thank  u, friend ,Maybe my expression error ... i just want ask that:my username&password is right ,but How do I know if I logined? use grep  keyword or cookie ? Not to say the command success or failure!

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the website and also on you to decide whether the operation is successful(in terms of login or not). As you mentioned about **grep**, here are few cases.

Case-1: You can check for the text **Logout**(or the logout link) on the response HTML. It means you have logged in, and now want to do logout.

Case-2: Check for Dashboard, My Account, etc type of text from the response.

Actually its up to you which keywords/texts you should look for to decide about logged in or not!